# How to Invoke-Command and pass path to command as parameter

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm tearing my hair out trying to invoke-command but pass the path to the exe as a parameter

eg:
I want to take this command

```
powershell Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { param($command ) C:\windows\system32\getmac.exe /$command } -ArgumentList ?
```

and translate it into a form like this

```
powershell Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { param($path, $command ) $path\getmac.exe /$command } -ArgumentList C:\windows\system32,?
```

I've tried all manner of quoting, ampersands and other contortions but can't get it to work. The above attempt results in

**Unexpected token '\getmac.exe' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:97**

(I don't really want to invoke getmac on localhost, this is the runnable, SO distilled version)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this option. It shows me help for `cscript.exe`.

```
C:\>powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { param($path, $command ) cmd /c $path $command } -args '"C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe"','"/?"'
```

I tried other options using `&` and then path and arguments and it was giving me missing `}` exception.  Then using `cmd /c` instead of `&` inside scriptblock fixed the issue.

Comment: thanks - this works. Was hoping to not have to use the cmd trick but it is the only working solution I've found.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell won't parse a string as a command that way. For e.g. if you do this:

```
$path="C:\Windows\System32"
$path\getmac.exe
```

You would get the same error. The trick to work around this is to use the invoke operator `&`:

```
&$path\getmac.exe
```

or in your example, like this (also note that for a command that you pass to the powershell executable, you must wrap it in scriptblock braces):

```
powershell -command {Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { param($path, $command ) &$path\getmac.exe /$command } -ArgumentList C:\windows\system32,?}
```

Comment: I tried this tack but adding & to the invoke-command changes the error to 'Missing closing '}' in statement block.' (try running your example with localhost for server).

Comment: @fiat just noticed you were executing through powershell executable, try wrapping the whole command in braces.

Comment: no joy :( similar missing closing '}' error. Note that without the $path param it works fine without the outer braces.

Comment: hmmm. I was running PS2.0, upgraded to PS3.0, same result. OS=Win7, running from command prompt, not PS prompt. tweaked your answer to run against localhost so exact copy paste repro.

Comment: @fiat did you check my solution by replacing `&` with `cmd /c` and including your parameters in quotes?