# PowerShell execute Sqlpackage.exe remotely

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute the `sqlpackage.exe` remotely as follows

```
$SqlPackage = "C:\SqlPackage.exe"
[string[]] $Properties = @("/p:DropObjectsNotInSource=true","/p:ScriptDatabaseCompatibility=true","/p:CommandTimeout=0", "/p:RegisterDataTierApplication=true")

$Params=@("/Action:Publish","/TargetServerName:""$ServerInstance""","/TargetDatabaseName:""$TargetDatabaseName""","/SourceFile:""$SourceFile""","$Variables")

$p="$Params $Properties"    
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& $SqlPackage } -ArgumentList @p -Session $session
```

But I got an exception as follows

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'A'.

So can some one help me how to resolve

Comment: Why are you using splatting syntax? `-ArgumentList @p` As you props are not hashtables I would expect odd behavior. What happens if you change that to `-ArgumentList $p`? It might also be sending that as one argument. Leaving it as the array type, instead of string, might get better results. `$p= $Params + $Properties`

Comment: You mean to say `$p=$Params+$Properties
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& $SqlPackage } -ArgumentList $p -Session $session`

Comment: If so I am getting different error The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.

Comment: Something like that yes. Without testing I am not sure how that would _exactly_ work but I feel the way you are passing arguments is the issue. Also you are not passing the args to the scriptblock either.

Comment: I think also `$sqlpackage` is null in the scriptblock since it is not in scope. that is what argument list is for.

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {write-output $SqlPackage } ....` produces what result?

Comment: Pretty sure what you want is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862549/how-to-invoke-command-and-pass-path-to-command-as-parameter

Comment: `$SqlPackage = "C:\SqlPackage.exe"` will give me the path where exe resides so it is not null

Comment: Are you running that against a remote system? Is should be null since that variable is not defined in that scope (unless you run it locally). Looked at the dupe and it shows how to run this with variables and use them in the script block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135389/discussion-between-dotnet-and-matt).